# Rename tag [posgresql-parallel-scan] to [postgresql-parallel-query]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There is a typo in the tag [posgresql-parallel-scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/posgresql-parallel-scan).

Would be [postgresql-parallel-scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql-parallel-scan). But I suggest the more suitable [postgresql-parallel-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql-parallel-query). That's the commonly used term as can be seen in the [Postgres Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Parallel_Query) and the [Postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/parallel-query.html).

Comment: There were 2 questions tagged [tag:posgresql-parallel-scan], one of which was wrongly tagged. With only 1 question left, you can easily retag and edit the wiki for the new tag.

Comment: @approxiblue: Thanks, that's what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As advised, I created a new tag [postgresql-parallel-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql-parallel-query), transferred  the updated tag info and removed the remaining faulty tag.
I assume garbage collection takes care of the unlinked tag.